# How to find the best possible match for 2 strings between 2 different long ArrayLists

Tags: java, regex, string

Lets say, I have say 2 lists:

```
A = { "ABC" , "DEF" , "JKL"};
```

and in some other project a second list:

```
A = { "ABC.com" , "DEF" , "JKL" };
```

Now ABC and ABC.com are the same because I know it after seeing it manually. But with a list with 10000 or 1 million entries. I need to find the best possible match for String ABC in the other list as, there is no fixed pattern that it will have to have .com, it could have been, .inc or something like that and it's sure, no other entry will have ABC in it because in reality it is Model Name for a device. For example, it would be something like "Cisco" and "Cisco.Inc".

What is the best strategy or regex that will find the best possible match for 2 strings?

Comment: why not use `String#contains`?. Also you need to define what *best possible match* means. Yes, the time complexity will be around `O(n) * O(n)`

Comment: Be more specific when you ask best possible match. What does it mean?

Comment: Commonly used is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance, but I don't know what exactly do you need.

Comment: @TheLostMind best possible match means, like in the example I took, i am looking for ABC to match with ABC.com or anything, so the comparison could be between ABC.inc and ABC.xyz.inc , so contains, would not work here. I hope I am making it clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of very good algorithms that solve the task of comparing the similarity between two strings (**string similarity masures**) such as:

1. [Dice's coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient)
2. [Overlap similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap_coefficient)
3. [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)
4. [Cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)
5. [Jaccard similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)
6. [Jaro-Winkler distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance)
7. (...)

All of them have their advantages / disadvantages. There is also a [Github Repository](https://github.com/tdebatty/java-string-similarity) with pre-implemented algorithms of similarity/distance measures. It is well documented and offers a whole variety of different algorithms. It is definitely a starting point worth to look at.

Here you'll find [Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_similarity_measures) with further references to more similarity algorithms.

Comment: The api for Levenshtein distance really did the trick, thanks !!

Answer (score 5):

You need to define a function to know the "distance" between two strings.

Basically you need a function that take two strings in input and return a value representing the distance. Comparing the different distances you can find the most similar string.

An example of distance function is the [Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) function.

[Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance) you can find functions in different languages implementing the Levenshtein function. The following code is the java implementation taken from that site:

```
public class LevenshteinDistance {                                               
    private static int minimum(int a, int b, int c) {                            
        return Math.min(Math.min(a, b), c);                                      
    }                                                                            

    public static int computeLevenshteinDistance(CharSequence lhs, CharSequence rhs) {      
        int[][] distance = new int[lhs.length() + 1][rhs.length() + 1];        

        for (int i = 0; i <= lhs.length(); i++)                                 
            distance[i][0] = i;                                                  
        for (int j = 1; j <= rhs.length(); j++)                                 
            distance[0][j] = j;                                                  

        for (int i = 1; i <= lhs.length(); i++)                                 
            for (int j = 1; j <= rhs.length(); j++)                             
                distance[i][j] = minimum(                                        
                        distance[i - 1][j] + 1,                                  
                        distance[i][j - 1] + 1,                                  
                        distance[i - 1][j - 1] + ((lhs.charAt(i - 1) == rhs.charAt(j - 1)) ? 0 : 1));

        return distance[lhs.length()][rhs.length()];                           
    }                                                                            
}
```

You can use it as follow:

```
public String mostSimilar(String toBeCompared, String[] strings) {
    int minDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    String similar = null;
    for (String str : strings) {
        int d = LevenshteinDistance.computeLevenshteinDistance(str, toBeCompared);
        if (d < minDistance) {
            minDistance = d;
            similar = str;
        }
    }
    return similar;
}
```

---

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) a quite complete list of string metric functions.

Comment: Yes, Levenshtein distance was a help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your regex would be something like that:

```
String s = "ABC";
String pattern = s + "(\.(com|uk|inc|biz|me|<put other domains here>)?)?"
```

**EDIT:** According to the discussion in comments:

```
String s = "ABC";
String pattern = s + ".*"
```

Comment: It would be ok, if the domains are known. But, it can be anything, can you suggest something more generic.

Comment: The set of domains is finite. Would you please explain better what is your acceptance criteria?

Comment: domain was just an example, in actual it could be anything,
Say "Cisco" and "Cisco Ltd." or "Cisco Ltd." and "Cisco Pvt Ltd"

Comment: Would you accept `Cisco Company From San Francisco`?

Comment: Sure, could be anything

Comment: check my edit - this regex means exactly what you said. Match string appended with anything.